# How can you two color in plot matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make a script to show me a picture like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzx2chi0jbclf66/Figura.jpg

The code is:

```
a = load('file.txt');
x = a(:,1);
y = a(:,4);
area(x,y)
```

But not like making out two colors, I think `bruh` command is used but not sure?

Comment: and..... what have you tried !?

Comment: Try this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html and this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237174 and then come back with some code

Answer (score 3):

This submission on the File Exchange might also help:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7255-areashade